# Windows C# Form Sliding with Native Api leaving shadow behind

Tags: c#

I am using below function to slide window (C# winform) open / close

```
public const int AW_HIDE = 0X10000;
public const int AW_ACTIVATE = 0X20000;
public const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0X1;
public const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;
public const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
public const int AW_BLEND = 0X80000;
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int AnimateWindow
(IntPtr hwand, int dwTime, int dwFlags);
```

Window Open Sliding Code

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    NativeMethods.AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 500, NativeMethods.AW_SLIDE | NativeMethods.AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | NativeMethods.AW_ACTIVATE);

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Winodw Close Sliding Code

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);

    if (e.Cancel  == false)
    {
        NativeMethods.AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 1000, NativeMethods.AW_HIDE | NativeMethods.AW_HOR_POSITIVE | NativeMethods.AW_SLIDE);
    }
}
```

above code leaving shadow effect after closing form and its not cleared any how. (sample screenshot attached)

[image: Shadow Screenshot]

please help me to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: No repro.  You might have to tell us more about this form.

Comment: This form display some progress of my running process. if process completed then it will automatic hide from screen.